# Modifing Symfony Form component choices inside the Form class

Tags: php, symfony, callback, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

I would like to know the correct/standard way to modify dropdown box content *within* a SF2 form class.

I would like the key to be the same as the array, which the markup below shows.

Should that be done within a callback rather than a pre-cursor to calling `$builder->add` as I am doing?

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array                $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    foreach ($options['importDirectories'] as $key => $value) {
        $formattedImportDirectories[$options['importDirectories'][$key]] = $value;
    }

    $builder
        ->add('importDirectory', 'choice', [
            'label'   => 'Import Directory',
            'choices' => $formattedImportDirectories
        ]);
}
```

Which produces a dropdown like this.

```
<select class="form-control" name="import_directory_type[importDirectory]" id="import_directory_type_importDirectory">
    <option value="14-products">14-products</option>
    <option value="14-course">14-course</option>
    <option value="14-accessories">14-accessories</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite straightforward and does not require a callback:

```
'choices' => array_combine($options['importDirectories'], $options['importDirectories']);
```